# Python: Tengo un archivo TXT y quiero generar una tupla con los datos de una columna

Tags: python, txt

Necesito importar un archivo de texto a una tupla en *Python*, los datos del archivo son como sigue, lo recorté solo como ejemplo ya que son muchos los registros que contiene:

```
3654742449.47
3654742463.27
3654742468.27
3654742473.27
3654742478.27
3654742483.27
3654742493.27   122.11  0.13    100.00  0.00
3654742498.27   123.56  0.14    100.00  0.00
3654742503.27   123.82  0.15    100.00  0.00
3654742508.27   124.20  0.17    100.00  0.00
3654742513.27   125.09  0.20    100.00  0.00
3654742518.27   126.53  0.22    100.00  0.00
```

Ya pude recorrer el archivo y generar un `print` y me muestra únicamente desde el *renglón 6* hasta el final. Sólo los datos de la *2a columna* (son los datos que me interesan únicamente).

```
122.11
123.56
123.82
124.2
125.09
126.53
```

Ahora lo que quiero es hacer una tupla con esos datos tal y como lo muestro enseguida, solo que me atoré y no sé como seguir.

y1 = (122.11, 123.56, 123.82, 124.20, 125.09, 126.53)

Este es el código que llevo hasta el momento:

```
datos2=[]

file=open('grafica.txt','r')
contenido=file.readlines()
for i in range (6,len(contenido),1): #(usaré como separador el tabulador)
   dato1=contenido[i].find('\t')
   dato2=contenido[i].find('\t',dato1+1)
   dato3=contenido[i].find('\t',dato2+1)

   # .....   Así sucesivamente hasta que posiciones todos los separadores

   valor2=float(contenido[i][dato1+1:dato2])

   datos2.append(valor2)

   print(valor2)
```

Por otro lado si pongo `print(datos2)` en lugar de `print(valor2)` me salen varias listas y la última es la que necesito y convertirla a tupla, solo que no sé tampoco cómo hacerle para obtener solo esa y no las que están arriba.

```
[122.11]
[122.11, 123.56]
[122.11, 123.56, 123.82]
[122.11, 123.56, 123.82, 124.2]
[122.11, 123.56, 123.82, 124.2, 125.09]
[122.11, 123.56, 123.82, 124.2, 125.09, 126.53]
```

Este es el código donde tengo que reemplazar la tupla `y1` con los datos arriba mencionados para poder generar la gráfica.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

y1 = (122.11, 123.56, 123.82, 124.20, 125.09, 126.53)

color1 = ('green')

pyplot.plot(y1, color=color1, linewidth=2, marker="o", label="temperatura")

pyplot.title("Gráficas de temperaturas en grados celcius")
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.grid()
pyplot.show()
```

Gracias de antemano

Gabriel Castillo

Comment: Bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no pongas capturas de pantalla con el código y texto relevante. Copia y pega el texto en la pregunta para que también nosotros podamos copiarlo en nuestros entornos de desarrollo para intentar reproducir el problema. Además de esa tenemos [varias razones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/92278) por las que queremos evitar las captura de pantalla de texto y código . También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, una disculpa a todos. En lo sucesivo voy a acatar las indicaciones. Saludos

Comment: Gabriel, no hay problema. Solo fué un comentario para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y tengas mas chance de obtener una respuesta de calidad. Puedes presionar en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/312106/edit) para modificar tu pregunta con las sugerencias del comentario anterior.

Answer (score 0):

seguro que habrá alguna forma más pythonesca pero aquí tienes mi propuesta.

```
import pandas as pd 
iris = pd.read_csv("iris .data.txt",na_values=[" "])#Cargo archivo txt desde mi directorio ya que no se abría tu ejemplo
p=iris.drop(iris.columns[[ 2,3,4]], axis=1) #elimino las columnas que no quieres
p.columns = ['a1','a2']#nombro columnas restantes para mejor visualización
pp=p[1:7]#selecciono las filas que quieres
subset = pp[['a1', 'a2']] #convierto a tupla
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
print (iris)#visualizo dataframe inicial
print (pp) #visualizo dataframe que quieres (dos columnas y seis filas)
print (tuples)#visualizo tupla resultante
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. He ejecutado el código pero me arroja un error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba_panda.py", line 3, in <module>
    p=iris.drop(iris.columns[[ 2,3,4]], axis=1) #elimino las columnas que no quieres
  File "C:\Users\pcson01\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4291, in __getitem__
    result = getitem(key)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

***Repl Closed***

Comment: Buenas Gabriel, he vuelto a ejecutar el codigo y no me da error, los has ejecutado desde tu consola con Python 3.7?.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo es perfecto y hace justamente lo que necesitas. Si entendi bien tu problema, lo unico que necesitas es obtener el resultado en forma de tupla. Pues bien, solo tienes que hacer un cast explicito:

```
datos2 = tuple(datos2)
```

tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
datos2=[]

file=open('grafica.txt','r')
contenido=file.readlines()
for i in range (6,len(contenido),1): #(usaré como separador el tabulador)
    dato1=contenido[i].find('\t')
    dato2=contenido[i].find('\t',dato1+1)
    dato3=contenido[i].find('\t',dato2+1)

    # .....   Así sucesivamente hasta que posiciones todos los separadores

    valor2=float(contenido[i][dato1+1:dato2])

    datos2.append(valor2)

    print(valor2)

datos2 = tuple(datos2)
```

Puedes comprobar que es una tupla del siguiente modo:

```
print(type(datos2))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación. Con esta línea solucioné el problema:

´´´´
cadena_f = tuple(float(i) for i in datos2)
´´´

Answer (score 0):

A continuación les muestro el código terminado:
1.- El programa descarta las primeras seis lineas 
2.- Se recorre el archivo de texto y se genera una tupla con los datos de la segunda columna, dicha tupla convierte los datos string a float.
3.- Se pasa la tupla como eje de las Y para generar la gráfica.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datos2=[]

file=open('c:\\graficas\\1_358722296.txt','r')
contenido=file.readlines()
for i in range (6,len(contenido),1): 

    #(usaré como separador el tabulador)
    dato1=contenido[i].find('\t')
    dato2=contenido[i].find('\t',dato1+1)
    dato3=contenido[i].find('\t',dato2+1)


    valor2=float(contenido[i][dato1+1:dato2])
    datos2.append(valor2)


cadena_f = tuple(float(i) for i in datos2)


plt.plot(cadena_f, color='blue', linewidth=2, label="Temperatura" )
plt.title(u'"Gráficas de temperaturas en Grados Fahrenheit"') 
plt.ylabel('Grados Fahrenheit')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Numero de muestras registradas')
#plt.xlim(0)
plt.ylim(0,300)

plt.show()
```

Muchas gracias a todos por sus aportaciones.

Gabriel Castillo